# anyone knows the manufacterer of this grid control?

Tags: user-interface

It is amazing.Each combobox cell has specific items(I couldn't show in the picture).
http://up.vatandownload.com/images/f6sq44ycqe34ptw37m42.jpg

Comment: It doesn't look amazing take a look at DevExpress or Telerik for far better ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omicron Electronics:
http://www.omicron.at/en/products/pro/secondary-testing-calibration/cmc-156/